# AWK: append text in the middle of output file

Tags: awk, hex

I'm completely new to AWK and I'm trying to create a C style array from a comma separated file. Here's the input file EE.hex. The length (number of hex numbers if this file may vary):

```
0x01 , 0x00 , 0x05 , 0x00 , 0x08 , 0x1C , 0x00 , 0x58 ,
0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 ,
0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 , 0x03 ,
0x03 , 0x03 , 0x01 , 0x00 , 0x23 , 0x00 , 0x08 , 0x00 ,
0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,
0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,
0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,
0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,
0x01 , 0x00 , 0x5B , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x80 ,
```

This is the AWK script I've been working on (EE.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

EEPROM_FILE="$1"  # First parameter - DSP parameter file

awk '

BEGIN {
printf("const uint8_t DSP_eeprom[] =\n{\n")

array_size=0
}



{
  # Format hex EEPROM array properly
  if ($1 ~ "0x.") 
    {print "  " $1 $2, $3 $4, $5 $6, $7 $8 "\n  " $9 $10, $11 $12, $13 $14, $15 $16}

  # Count how many bytes there is in the array were creating
    for(i=1; i < NF; i++) {
      if ($i ~ "0x.") {
        array_size++
      } 
    }

}


END {

printf("};\n")

{print "//I want the calculated array size "array_size" to be inserted between the [] brackets, not at the end like this!"}

}' "$EEPROM_FILE" > EE.h
```

The output file (EE.h) looks like this:

```
const uint8_t DSP_eeprom[] =
{
  0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00,
  0x08, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x58,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00,
  0x23, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x01, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,

};
//I want the calculated array size 72 to be inserted between the [] brackets
```

As you can already see in the comment, I need the number of hex numbers to be placed between the square brackets, not at the end. Is there any way I can

- **A)** Insert the number between the square brackets?
- **B)** Insert a pre-formatted line on the line before the **{** character?

The **desired output** looks like this, with the calculated length inserted between the square brackets:

```
const uint8_t DSP_eeprom[72] =
{
  0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00,
  0x08, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x58,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
  0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00,
  0x23, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x01, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the main topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `gawk` you can simply a bit

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v RS='^$' -v OFS=', ' '
      {print "const uint8_t DSP_eeprom[" NF-1 "] =\n{";
       for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s", $i OFS ((i+4)%8?"":ORS)}
  END {print "\n};" }' file

const uint8_t DSP_eeprom[72] =
{
0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00,
0x08, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x58,
0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
0x03, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00,
0x23, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x01, 0x00, 0x5B, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Since I'm a newbie I prefer my own "verbose" way of writing the script.

So there isn't another way than to modify FS, RS and OFS? I'm also using this script to pull out some C macros from one file, then create the DSP_eeprom array from file no. 2 - the EE.hex file. I wrote the example above to isolate the problem as much as possible. Maybe it's easier if I upload the full script plus the other input file as well? I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I've never done this before. Do I have to edit my main post or can I use the "Answer Your Question" button below?